# Taking an Openshift cluster out of load

Tags: openshift, istio

We have two large geo-reserved Openshift clusters with over 100 pods deployed in each cluster, using Istio Service Mesh. The applications on the clusters are geo-routed with healthcheck (L7).

What is the best way to take an entire cluster off load?

We don't have access to the infrastructure, it's maintained by another team, so the Haproxy setup doesn't work for us.
So far the only idea is to change VirtualService and implement [HTTPFaultInjection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#HTTPFaultInjection) for the time of work, then rollback, but this looks like a crutch, I would like to find a more elegant solution.